# Remove extra space and fix offset at top of search bar in sheet SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

[image]

I'm having two issues:

- There's an additional space on top of search bar in my bottom sheet when search field is not active.
- There's some overlap between search bar and drag visibility indicator when search field is active

Here's my code:

```
  struct SheetView: View {
  @State var isPresented: Bool = true
  @StateObject var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel()
  @State var text: String = ""
  @State var isSearchActive : Bool = false
  @State var defaultSelectedDetent : PresentationDetent = .fraction(0.35)
  
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Text("Hello world")
        Color(UIColor.systemGray)
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented){
        DefaultView(..., isSearchActive: $searchViewModel.isSearchActive){
          index in
          searchViewModel.selectSearch(selectionIndex: index)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchViewModel.query, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
          .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.1),.fraction(0.35), .large], selection: $defaultSelectedDetent)
          .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
          .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
          .onChange(of: searchViewModel.isSearchActive){newValue in
            if newValue{
              defaultSelectedDetent = .large
            }else{
              defaultSelectedDetent = .fraction(0.35)
            }
          }
          //.padding(.top, $searchViewModel.isSearchActive.wrappedValue ? 12 : -32)
          
      }
      
    }
  }
```

One option I've tried is to use an environment value to control state. I used this to fix the padding (commented out in SheetView). It works but the animation is poor if the presentation detent isn't also changing(see GIF below). I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to execute this.

I am unable to hide navigationBar because hiding this will hide the search bar.

```
struct DefaultView: View{
  ...
  @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
  @Binding var isSearchActive: Bool
  ...
   
  var body: some View {
          NavigationStack {
              List {
                ...
              }
              .listStyle(.plain)
              .navigationTitle("")
              .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
              .onChange(of: isSearching){newValue in
                isSearchActive = newValue
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Padding change without presentation detent change:

[image]